# Dúvida manipulação de valores js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho os seguintes inputs no html:

```
COD_01     VALOR_01
COD_02     VALOR_02
e asim por diante até....
COD_99     VALOR_99
```

O usuário vai alimentar cada COD e VALOR.

Preciso criar um js para:

```
1- Somar todos os Valores, por COD.
2- Preciso exibir um alerta caso a soma de algum código ultrapasse de 1000
```

Exemplo:

```
COD_01       VALOR_01
201           200,00
COD_02       VALOR_02
202           100,00
COD_03       VALOR_03
201           900,00
```

Como o valor do código 201 passou de 1000, então exibir mensagem:

```
Atenção! O valor do código 201 passou de R$ 1000,00
```

Podem fazer o uso de jquery, sem problemas.

Comment: Bote o que você já tentou e qual realmente a sua dúvida, o dever de casa deve ser iniciado por você

Comment: Marcus, como não manjo de javascript e sim de banco de dados, se ninguém me responder o que vou fazer é o seguinte: um ajax no evento de change em cada input de valor inserindo em uma tabela do banco de dados e lá eu manipulo o que precisar. No entanto não quero fazer isso por ser uma bazuca para matar uma formiga.
Agora, em javascript não saiu nada realmente. Não sei nem o que colocar no google para pesquisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia é criar um objeto e ir adicionando os códigos que não existem e somando os valores. Quando um código existente no objeto ultrapassar 1000, exibe o alerta:

```js
var codigos = {};

var cods = $("input[name*='cod_']");
var vals = $("input[name*='valor_']");

cods.on("blur", function(){
   var cod = $(this).val();
   if(codigos[cod] == null && cod){
      codigos[cod] = 0;
   }
});

vals.on("blur", function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val){
      var cod_val = $(this).prev("input[name*='cod_']").val();
      var valor = parseFloat(val.replace(".", "").replace(',','.'));
   
      if(codigos[cod_val] + valor > 1000){
         alert("Atenção! O valor do código "+cod_val+" passou de R$ 1000,00");
      }else{
         codigos[cod_val] += valor;
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="código" type="text" name="cod_01" />
<input placeholder="valor" type="text" name="valor_01" />
<br />
<input placeholder="código" type="text" name="cod_02" />
<input placeholder="valor" type="text" name="valor_02" />
<br />
<input placeholder="código" type="text" name="cod_03" />
<input placeholder="valor" type="text" name="valor_03" />
<br />
<input placeholder="código" type="text" name="cod_04" />
<input placeholder="valor" type="text" name="valor_04" />
```

Comment: Amigo, não funcionou da forma como mencionei. Não está agrupando por código. Está apenas somando o valor total.

Comment: @Y.Menon Não tinha percebido esse detalhe... vou reformular a resposta...

Comment: @Y.Menon Creio que agora irá funcionar.

Comment: perfeito! obrigado!